# SQL inline IF statement to display column names and strings

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run an IF statement in my SQL:

```
IF(customer = 'Y', contact_name + '(' + contact_email + ')', 'Internal')
```

the statement works with its true and false but I want to be able to display

`contact_name` (table column)

and then in brackets next to this, it would display `contact_email` which is also a table column.

I am having trouble with the brackets around `contact_email`.

my full query is:

```
SELECT datetime as datetime, notes as notes 
FROM customer_communication 
WHERE company = '276' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT datetime as datetime, 
       CONCAT('Ticket #', + ticketnumber, + 
              ' () Opened By ', + 
              IF(customer = 'Y', contact_name '(' contact_email ')', 
                                 'Internal')) as notes 
FROM tickets 
WHERE company = '276'
```

and I am seeing this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''(' contact_email ')', 'Internal')) as notes FROM tickets WHERE
>   company = '276' ' at line 1

Comment: What database are you using?  What error are you getting?

Comment: You probably want a CASE expression.  IF is usually control-of-flow in most RDBMSs.

Comment: Please tag the database that you're using, show the full statement that you're trying to run, and include any exact error messages that you're receiving. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: check my latest update, ive included full query and error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT datetime as datetime, notes as notes 
FROM customer_communication 
WHERE company = '276' 

UNION ALL 

SELECT datetime as datetime, 
       CONCAT('Ticket #', 
              ticketnumber, 
              ' () Opened By ', 
              IF(customer = 'Y', contact_name + '(' + contact_email + ')'
                               , 'Internal')) as notes 
FROM tickets 
WHERE company = '276'
```